# Compiling JAVAFX in Netbeans 7.3.1 + JDK1.7.0_40

Tags: java, netbeans

I had JDK 1.7.0_25 and Netbeans 7.3.1 as well as Javafx + Scenebuilder 1.1 installed on Window 7 64-bit. All worked fine. Now that a newer JAVA is out, I uninstalled everything then downloaded and installed the Netbeans 7.3.1 + JDK 1.7.0_40 bundle and installed Scene builder 1.1. Supposedly, this should have JAVAFX included. I've also changed the PATH variable to point to C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin. Java projects compile fine. However, JAVAFX projects fail with the message:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java"

The java platforms all point to JDK 1.7.0_40.

Is there some other place which might still be pointing to jdk1.7.0_25?

Any help is much appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: Running IntelliJ in Java7u40 leads to strange GUI behaviour.  I suspect there is a lot of changes under the bonnet in this update.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like you need to edit your project settings and set the project's build and run SDKs to the right location. If these are set, they'll be overriding the PATH variable.

Comment: Many thanks. It is not obvious to me how to do this. If I open the 'Project properties' dialog, where should I set this? The Default JavaFX Platform seems to be ok. However, there is under 'Libraries' 'Run' tab a Broken reference: dist.jar and a warning sign saying some library items cannot be located. Use Reference Problems dialog (where is this dialog?).

Comment: That missing `dist.jar` isn't a problem. What about the dialog from Libraries -> Manage Platforms -> Default JavaFX Platform? Are there any errors under the JavaFX tab? Note that NetBeans expects you to use the Default JavaFX platform, rather than simply a JDK.

Comment: Here are the entries:

Comment: Here are the entries: Platform folder C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40. Enable JavaFX checked. JavaFX SDK: C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40. JavaFX Runtime: C:\Program Files\jdk1.7.0_40\jre. JavaFX Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/. JavaFX Sources: Empty. There appear no error messages. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: OK, that's good. If the Classes list has nothing from the other JDK (which would be weird), I would make sure that you haven't got any other platforms defined that are looking in the wrong place (and delete any you find). I'd also check the Run settings on the project properties dialog. Anything weird?

Comment: Failing that, I'd use your OS to search all the files within the project folder for the string `jdk1.7.0_25`. If it's found anywhere, I'd edit that file and just change the JDK location. If it's not, check your Java settings from the Tools -> Options dialog.

Comment: Got it to work! There were 2 files. One was 'build.properties' and the other was Default_JavaFX_Platform.xml. They are located in C:\Users\(myself)\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\7.3.1. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Excellent! Please remember to accept the answer if it has helped.